# A header file is not found in Xcode

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, googleads-mobile-unity

I developed an endless ball rolling game for IOS with Unity.
The game includes a revive function.

I want to show an Google ad video before the revive function. If the player has watched fully the ad video, then the revive function will be called otherwise not.

The problem is when I want to Build & Run my game on Xcode but Xcode will not run my game because I get the following error:

> 'VungleAdapter/VungleAdNetworkExtras.h' file not found

[image: Xcode image with error]

I do not know what is error is and I want to solve the problem. 
It is very strange to get this error because I am only programming on Visual Studio.

Comment: I have a similar problem when I set up Admob Mediation for my project and add Vungle as one of the ad networks. So please suggest me some solution for this!!

Comment: I tried to integrate this - https://github.com/Vungle/AdMob-iOS-Adapter/tree/master/VungleAdapter - within the Xcode project but problem not solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Navigate to Build Phases, expand Compile Sources, delete file it says it's missing, add it back and then build the project again. Also Cleaning(Swift+CMD+K) the project might also work.

Did you write the VungleExtrasBuilder.h file extension wrong with "h" instead of "m", 'cause in the file shown on the right it's with ".m" Did you?

Comment: I tried what you said but nothing works unfurtunately. I did not developed anything in Xcode.

Comment: Currently, I am facing the same error - Within Compile Sources VungleAdNetworkExtras.h file not present so I can do what you have suggested.